# Where are the Fedora livecd-creator YUM groups defined?

Tags: fedora, yum, live-cd

When using the Fedora livecd-creator tool the kickstart files include yum groups such as @base-x @standard @firefox etc. which are defined in the %packages section.
Where are these groups defined? I want to know what packages each group includes.
You can use "yum grouplist" to list the ones currently installed but livecd-creator must have it's own yum.conf somewhere but I can't find it.

Thanks.